# I am trying to crawl a website using scrapy and storing the scraped data into variables of item class

Tags: python-2.7, import, scrapy, nameerror

I have a spider file dmoz_spider.py and it contets are:

```
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from dmoz.items import DmozItem


    class DmozSpider(Spider):
       name = "dmoz"
       allowed_domains = ["m.timesofindia.com"]
       start_urls = ["http://m.timesofindia.com/india/Congress-BJP-spar-over-Gujarat-govts-Rs-11-per-day-poverty-line/articleshow/29830237.cms"]

       def parse(self, response):
            sel = Selector(response)
                torrent = DmozItem()
                filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]+"1.txt"
            torrent['link']  = response.url
            torrent['title']  = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract() 
                open(filename, 'wb').write(torrent['link'])
```

2nd file is items.py

```
   from scrapy.item import Item, Field

     class DmozItem(Item):
        title = Field()
        link = Field()
        desc = Field()
```

I am getting following error on command line when i run my crawler...

> **ImportError: No module named dmoz.items**

as to when i removed the import statement from my spider file it gave me error saying

> **exceptions.NameError: global name 'DmozItem' is not defined**

Comment: what's your project directory structure? (starting from where your `scrapy.cfg` is, assuming your created your project with `scrapy startproject`)

Comment: sorry @pault. problem is solved now should have updated it. Instead of from dmoz.items it should be from tutorial.items import * ,instead of directory name was giving project name there. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the problem to my question and posting it so that if any one ends up on the similar problem he can get the answer.

in my code where I am doing this

```
 from dmoz.items import DmozItem
```

it should actually be

```
 from tutorial.items import DmozItem or

 from tutorial.items import *
```

since my project directory or package name is tutorial
That was the mistake I was doing earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing

```
item[title] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
```

instead of

```
item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
```